# Using Rematch Store in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I'm building a screen in React Native using expo. I'm new to both React Native and the Rematch framework, and I want to render the first and last names of the basketball players from this endpoint upon load: https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players

Here's my `models.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const players = {
  state: {
    players: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    SET_PLAYERS: (state, payload) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        players: payload,
      };
    },
  },
  effects: (dispatch) => ({
    async getPlayers() {
      let response = await axios.get(
        "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players"
      );
      let { data } = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      dispatch.players.SET_PLAYERS(data);
    },
  }),
};
```

`store.js`

```
import { init } from "@rematch/core";
import * as models from "./models";
const store = init({ models });
export default store;
```

And finally, my main screen:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./state_management/store";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Players />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Players = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      // PLAYER LIST HERE!!
    </Provider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Most examples I have seen online and on here are to do with onPress actions like increments, decrements etc. This involves managing data from an API call so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

In main screen as you are using functional component try using useDispatch and useSelector to dispatch and fetch the list and map it to your screen

```
 import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

 const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const responseList = useSelector(state => {
    return state.apiReducer.data
  })
```

In useEffect dispatch action to models

As from the question what i understand is a need of fetch the stored list from models and render players name, find code for the same in this [link](https://github.com/ritzblogs/ReactNative-Redux-ApiResponse)